# this.route.snapshot.params.get is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am new to Angular.I am building an Angular app and I want to get a parameter from the component route. I only have 1 component. So, when I go to **localhost:4200**I want to open my component, but when I go to **localhost:4200/v1/5** I want my component to open and to grab number 5 and then console.log it. I get the error from the title and I dont know why:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RacvaService } from './racva.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'RacveApp1';
  event:any;
  public racva: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(){
    let racva_id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params.get('id'));
    this.racva = racva_id;
    console.log(this.racva);
    }
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'v1/:id', component: AppComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [ AppComponent ];
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbPaginationModule,
    NgbAlertModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways

1 and **Recommended**

Subscribe to the queryParams so that each time it changes you get the updated  value

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  // your code
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
    });
}
```

Doc: https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information

2: To get it only once on component mount

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

Depending on your requirements, you may choose either one. The only advantage I see of the #1 is that since you're subscribing to the parameter change, it may be helpful in making async calls with the parameter.

Comment: When I add the 1st solution instead, it still doesn't work, says 'undefined' when I log it. It looks like this: `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
  });
    ` in OnInit. My routing is like this: `{ path: 'v1/:id', component: AppComponent}`

Comment: @OmarLittle You'll have to import ActivatedRoute as well! Answer updated.

Comment: as you can see in my code above, I added it before, still nothing :/